# regx to replace to build versions in file

Tags: regex, linux, unix, jenkins, sed

Need regex to replace Build version `1.0.0` with `1.0.2` in a properties file, and the file content looks something like the below mentioned;

```
Eagle-1.0.0
Chick-1.0.0
Bingo-1.0.0
```

I have tried the below but it's not working

```
sed -i "s/1\.0\.O\.[0-9.]*/1.0.0./g" file.txt
```

Comment: That second `0` you have looks suspiciously like an `O`...

Comment: Two questions: 1) Did you notice there's an "O" (capital-oh, vs. "zero"? and 2) Where's the "2" in 1.0.2 coming from?  SUGGESTION: `sed -i "s/1.0.0/1.0.2./g" file.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: @paulsm4: `.` needs to be escaped otherwise they will be interpreted as metacharacters by `sed` regex engine.

Comment: @Allan - you're correct, of course. Sigh... Thank you.  My original questions - and suggestion - remains.  With this correction:  `sed -i "s/1\.0\.0/1\.0\.2/g" file.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: @paulsm4: two other points I had not seen 1) -> if you use `-i` option the change will be directly done by sed on the original file and `> newfile.txt` will just create an empty file as the there is no output to `stdout` 2) -> in the replacement pattern you do not need to escape `.` (it is a detail). But you are completely right, he could just go for a `sed` without the `O` character (that looks like a `0`) anyway.

Comment: Sigh... again.  I keep reminding myself that I should never, ever answer a question without trying it out myself.  By which time 40 other people beat me to it :(  Anyway - thank you, and +1 for your response :)

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can just run the following `sed` command:

```
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ cat version 
Eagle-1.0.0 Chick-1.0.0 Bingo-1.0.0
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ sed -i".bak" 's/1\.0\.0/1.0.2/g' version
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ cat version
Eagle-1.0.2 Chick-1.0.2 Bingo-1.0.2
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ cat version.bak 
Eagle-1.0.0 Chick-1.0.0 Bingo-1.0.0
```

**Notes:**

- `-i".bak"` allow you to modify the file and to take a backup file just in case, same file name and suffix `.bak`
- You need to escape `.` otherwise they will be interpreted as metacharacters by `sed` regex engine.